# JQuery Mobile Notifications

Tags: php, jquery, sql, ajax, jquery-mobile

I have a notifications system that I'm trying to put into a jquery mobile app.  The system works on my website but I'm having a hard to getting it to work in the web app.  What's supposed to happen is when I click on the notification link, the panel opens up, and it shows my notifications.  Instead it's showing nothing.

Here is my code for the page:

```
<?php
//INFO FOR CONNECTING TO DATABASE AND SETTING $username.
?>

<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
<head>

<!--THIS IS FOR THE NOTIFICATIONS-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function toggleDiv(divId) {
   $("#"+divId).toggle();
$(document).ready(function(){
         $("#myContent").load("http://www.1511project.com/getnotes.php?name=<? echo $username; ?>");
    });
}
</script>
<!--END AJAX FOR NOTIFICATIONS-->


<script type= "text/javascript" src = "countries.js"></script>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
<title>15:11 Project Mobile</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
<link href="font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="js/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.js"></script>

<!--THIS IS FOR THE SHARE BUTTON-->
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('.toggleNotes').click(function() {        
$nextArticle = $(this).next('.article');        
$nextArticle.is(':visible') ? $nextArticle.slideUp() : $nextArticle.slideDown();       
return false;  
});
});
</script>

</head> 
<body> 



<?
//THIS GETS THE NUMBER OF UNREAD NOTIFICATIONS
$readquery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM notifications WHERE (needs='$username' AND needsread='0' AND type='workneed') OR (worker='$username' AND workerread='0')");
$number = mysql_num_rows($readquery);
?>


<!-- BEGIN PAGE 1 -->
<div data-role="page" id="feed" data-add-back-btn="true">
    <div data-role="panel" id="settingspanel" data-position="left" data-display="overlay">
        <!--THIS IS WHERE THE SETTINGS PANEL GOES-->
    </div>

    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-theme="c" data-tap-toggle="false" data-id="foo1" style="padding-top: 5px; border-bottom: 1px solid #eccfb3; padding-bottom: 5px;">
        <a href="#settingspanel" data-role="button" data-iconpos="notext" class="icon-reorder icon-2x" style="background: none; margin-left: 20px;"></a>
        <center><img src="images/logo_app_white.png" height="25px"></center>
        <a href="#myContent" data-role="button" data-iconpos="notext" class="icon-bell-alt icon-2x" style="background: none; margin-right: 20px;"></a><? echo $number; ?>
    </div>

    <div data-role="content">   

        *****The page content goes here*********

    </div>

        <!--THIS IS THE PANEL THAT SHOULD DISPLAY THE NOTIFICATIONS-->
    <div data-role="panel" id="myContent" data-position="right" data-display="overlay">


    </div>


</div>

<!-- END PAGE 1 -->
```

This is the getnotes.php page, it gets the info to display:

```
<?
$username = $row['username'];

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM notifications WHERE needs='$username' OR worker='$username' ORDER BY CASE WHEN needs = '$username' THEN needsread ELSE workerread END, time DESC");

while ($rows = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {

$needs = $rows['needs'];
$id = $rows['ID'];
$worker = $rows['worker'];
$title = $rows['title'];
$needsread = $rows['needsread'];
$workerread = $rows['workerread'];
$time = $rows['time'];
$type = $rows['type'];

if ($needsread == "0" && $username == "$needs" && $type== "workneed") {
  echo "<div style='background-color:#FFFFFF; border-color:#000000; border-width:1px; border-style:solid;'>$worker signed up to work your need: $title.</div>";
  mysql_query("UPDATE notifications SET needsread='1' WHERE ID='$id'");
}

if ($workerread == "0" && $username == "$worker" && $type== "workneed") {
  echo "<div style='background-color:#FFFFFF; border-color:#000000; border-width:1px; border-style:solid;'>You signed up to work $needs's need: $title.</div>";
  mysql_query("UPDATE notifications SET workerread='1' WHERE ID='$id'");
}

if ($workerread == "1" && $username == "$worker" && $type== "workneed") {
  echo "<div style='background-color:#d3d3d3; border-color:#000000; border-width:1px; border-style:solid;'>You signed up to work $needs's need: $title.</div>";
}

if ($needsread == "1" && $username == "$needs" && $type== "workneed") {
  echo "<div style='background-color:#d3d3d3; border-color:#000000; border-width:1px; border-style:solid;'>$worker signed up to work your need: $title.</div>";
}







if ($workerread == "0" && $username == "$worker" && $type == "follow") {
  echo "<div style='background-color:#FFFFFF; border-color:#000000; border-width:1px; border-style:solid;'><a href='viewprofile.php?viewusername=$needs'>$needs</a> started following you.</div>";
  mysql_query("UPDATE notifications SET workerread='1' WHERE ID='$id'");
}

if ($workerread == "1" && $username == "$worker" && $type == "follow") {
  echo "<div style='background-color:#d3d3d3; border-color:#000000; border-width:1px; border-style:solid;'><a href='viewprofile.php?viewusername=$needs'>$needs</a> started following you.</div>";
}

}


?>
```

Any ideas why it's working on my website but not working on my jquery mobile web app?

Answer (score -1):

Why do you have references to 2 different versions of jQuery? Apparently the toggle div function is never used, and your scripts and stylesheets are all over the place. This is clearly a very bad copy-paste job. Do you expect someone to re-write the entire thing for you?

Comment: Actually I just really suck at coding....I'm looking for the reason why it won't work...sorry it's not up to your standards oh great one.